# Saving file generated from Java Code to user defined location like download Functionality

Tags: java, file, save, jfilechooser

I have a requirement where i have to save a file that i m generating using my java code and but as when i want to save it i want to let user decide where they want to save it.Like a download option that comes when we download a file from internet.I have tried using `JFileChooser`. But it does not work the way i want it to work.Can somebody please help.
Im creating the file like

```
try{
    writer= new PrintWriter("F://map.txt", "UTF-8");
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Specify a file to save");   
JFrame parentFrame = new JFrame();

int userSelection = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(parentFrame);

if (userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File fileToSave = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    System.out.println("Save as file: " + fileToSave.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Comment: I do not see any code related to JFileChooser in your post?

Comment: @KickButtowsk i have put the code.as when i use this code.it simply ask me to select the file to save.i want my particular file to get saved at position specified by user

Answer (score 2):

**Writing to a file**

Note that this will overwrite the file if it exists, and **it will not automatically prompt you for sh*t** if it does. You have to check if it exists by yourself.

```
byte dataToWrite[] = // source
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("the-file-name");
out.write(dataToWrite);
out.close();
```

In your case this would probably read out as

```
if (userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File fileToSave = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    System.out.println("Save as file: " + fileToSave.getAbsolutePath());

    FileInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;

    try {

        in = new FileInputStream(source);
        out = new FileOutputStream(fileToSave.getPath());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

    }
    finally {
        if (in != null) in.close();
        if (out != null) out.close();
    }
}
```

Please note that this is untested code and I have no real routine with this stuff. You should google "java write file" or something like that if this proves to be erronous code :)

Comment: @user3678399 In that case please mark the answer as a solution :)

Comment: @user3678399: same here, please accept this answer.